# Issue with code version on Google App Script new editor

Tags: google-apps-script

I worked yesterday on a google app-script on my laptop.
I worked this morning on this script, I was on an other computer out of home.
When I came back to home. I opened my laptop and I keep working on the same script but on a different file and I do some tests and executions.

Now, I noticed my code from this morning is missing and overwriten by the code from yesterday who was on my laptop.

Is there a solution to recover my code ?

Answer (score 1):

Go back to the legacy editor, and select file > see version history. You will see your change log and be able to recover an earlier version there. The new editor doesn't have this feature yet.

I'll also toss in a plug for [clasp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp), which is a little tool to allow you to clone your apps script code to your local machine so you can check it into a source code repository.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately the last version in the version history is 2 hours later than my morning code.

Comment: :( That sucks. I don't think there's another way to recover, but maybe someone else will have a suggestion.

Comment: When I make changes that I want to save I save the entire project with Apps Script API as a JSON file and it doesn't create a new  project  it's just a simple ascii file and you can completely restore them with the Apps Script API